# Prime sieve: improve efficiency while keeping it reasonably simple?

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

```
public static void listPrimesThree(int maxNum){
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[maxNum+1];
int root = (int)Math.sqrt(maxNum);

for (int m = 2; m <= root; m++){
  for (int k = m*m; k <= maxNum; k+=m){
    booleanArray[k] = true;
  }
}
for (int m = 3; m <= maxNum; m+=2){
  if(!booleanArray[m]){
    System.out.println(m);
  }
}
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.err.println(endTime - startTime+"ms");
}
```

Comment: You can improve the efficiency by skipping sieving numbers that are already known to be composite.  For example, inside your first outer for loop, you could do `if (booleanArray[m]) continue;` to skip composite numbers.  I'm seeing 4-5x speed improvement with that one change for large values.

Comment: You can use a BitSieve. The one from java or better a custom one, because you know the number of primes inside the Integer range.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of memory bound problem. If you manage to reduce the number of cache misses you can have quite a speedup.
I am providing almost identical code, only instead of boolean array I am using BitSet. Running on Server machinve, on my quite dated hardware I observe about 30% speedup without any other optimizations. Hand-optimizing the bit set functionality may speed things a little more, although I am not too much an optimist.

I am providing this example only to show how important memory (micro) management can be. I do not suggest that the original algorithm can not be optimized.

```
public void listPrimesThree(int maxNum) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int root = (int) Math.sqrt(maxNum);

    BitSet bs = new BitSet(maxNum+1);
    for (int m = 2; m <= root; m++) {
        for (int k = m * m; k <= maxNum; k += m) {
            bs.set(k);
        }
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println((endTime - startTime) / 1000 + " s");
    for (int m = 3; m <= maxNum; m += 2) {
        if (!bs.get(m)) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you change it to work by segments, such that each segment fits into your cache entirely, you're supposed to get even more speedup.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Unfortunately cache sizes may vary wildly on different architectures. I am curious to see a cache oblivious https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm implementation of this problem (again, without adding too much complexity).

Answer (score 0):

In your second, output loop, `m` enumerates only odd numbers: `m = 3, 5, 7, 9, ...`. So we don't need to mark any evens in the first loop, as we skip them over anyway:

```
for (int m = 3; m <= root; m+=2) {
  if (!booleanArray[m]) {                    // if not marked as a composite:
    for (int k = m*m; k <= maxNum; k+=2*m) { //   mark only _odd_ multiples
      booleanArray[k] = true;                //   as composite
    }
  }
}
```

(also incorporating the advice you got in the comments, about only marking the multiples of *non*-composites). Incrementing **in steps of `2*m`** (going through *odds* only) cuts the overall amount of work in half.

---

Loop unrolling turns it into

```
if ((m=3) <= root) break;           // m = 3 .
if (!booleanArray[m]) {                    
    for (int k = m*m; k <= maxNum; k+=2*m) { 
      booleanArray[k] = true;       // k = 9, 15, 21, 27, ... 
    }                               //   all are composite, multiples of 3,
}                                   //   k = m*(m..+=2) = 3*i, i=3,5,7,9,11...

for (int i = 5; ; i+=6) {

  if ((m=i) <= root) break;         // m = 5, 11, 17, 23, ...
  if (!booleanArray[m]) {                       // m%6==5 for all m
    for (int k = m*m; k <= maxNum; k+=2*m) {    // (m==6x+5)
      booleanArray[k] = true;                
    }
  }

  if ((m=i+2) <= root) break;       // m = 7, 13, 19, 25, ...
  if (!booleanArray[m]) {                       // m%6==1 for all m
    for (int k = m*m; k <= maxNum; k+=2*m) {    // (m==6x+1)
      booleanArray[k] = true;                
    }
  }

  if ((m=i+4) <= root) break;       // m = 9, 15, 21, 27, ... 
  if (!booleanArray[m]) {                       // m%6==3 for all m
    for (int k = m*m; k <= maxNum; k+=2*m) {    // (m==6x+3)
      booleanArray[k] = true;                
    }                               // all k's are composite, multiples of 3,
  }                                 //   all are already marked in the (m==3) loop
}
```

It is clear now that the third sub-loop is totally superfluous. The first (`m==3`) loop marks all multiples of 3; we can skip this step also, if we'll skip over the multiples of 3 in the output stage. This saves 1/3rd of the remaining work, which makes it 3x speedup overall.

---

We can fold the remaining two sub-loops back into one loop:

```
for (int m = 5, n=6, k=4; m <= root; m += (k=n-k)) {
  if (!booleanArray[m]){                  // if prime - mark its multiples
    int j = m*m, l=6*m, i=4*m;            //   that are not mults of 2 nor 3
    if ( (m%6) == 1 ) { i=2*m; }          //   (be at the correct phase)
    for ( ; j <= maxNum; j += (i=l-i)) { 
      booleanArray[j] = true; 
    }   // k = 2, 4,  2,  4,  2,  4,  2, ...
  }    // m = 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, ...
}     // skipped:  9,     15,     21,     27,  ...
```

This uses the fact that for any even number `n` the value `n%6` is either 0, 2, or 4; and for any multiple `m` of 3, `m%6` is either 0 or 3. Which leaves only 1 and 5 for all the rest of the numbers.

Next, augment the output loop to work only with the {2,3}-coprimes as well:

```
System.out.println(3);                    // print 3 unconditionally
for (int m = 5, n=6, k=4; m <= maxNum; m += (k = n-k)) {
  if(!booleanArray[m]) {
    System.out.println(m);
  } 
}
```

---

The next step of improvement is to condense the array. Right now it hosts a lot of unused entries which we skip over.

Comment: Ah, sneaky, very sneaky.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm still reading your reply there; thanks BTW. I wish there was a simple way in Haskell to have arrays that are guaranteed to be mutable in-place.

Comment: No, no problem, I was just curious. Re the previous comment, `ST(U)Array`s are about as simple as it gets. But I suppose you think rather of a way to annotate "this one is used sequentially, don't bother copying, mutate in place" and write `nextStep (arr // updateList)`?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that would be great, thank you. ;) I'll take STUArrays, but I see you still had to tweak it even after you used unsafeThaw ... (still reading).

Comment: @Daniel (and I think, ultimately Haskell ought to compile into simple loops, in C, where possible) ... both test3 and test4 can be represented in C with simple loop on two register variables. And they *ought to*. (that's not mentioning the SuperSmart Compiler which would recognize that the 10 million swaps are equivalent to just 1 swap (or is it 0?)).

Comment: Will, `unsafeThaw` is minor there because the `ByteArray#` is only eight bytes, the constructor and the bounds/size components take far more. It would have made a far bigger impact if the array had, say 1000 elements. 0 swaps, `testN . testN = id`, and 10000000 is even.

Comment: ah, yes, thanks; *you are* like the super smart compiler. ;) but 10 mil is an arg to apply; what apply does with it is not immediately apparent. there's an (n-1) there... maybe it stops 1 short of the given n times? does it call a function one extra time before starting a loop? (so many opportunities to screw up...) (what I'm saying is I'm too lazy to check it up too closely... but now I did. hmm.)